# Could anyone explain these two sentences to me? I don’t really get what mindful and catching myself in a cycle mean

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I’d like to know what they mean by the sentences in bold.

> How is work going on the new album, Notes on a Conditional Form?

> MH: It's like half-way done. Sometimes we'll write a song and it has a really traditional form, and we'll go, "Oh, that's cool". A 'song-song' we call it. And then a lot of stuff is less linear, all over the place. But we just love the way it exists like that too. With this record at the moment, I'm constantly thinking, we're getting pretty big, can we really make a record like this? Can we really make a record that the only thing we thought about is, am I vibing on this?

> GD: It's definitely just [about] getting better at our own craft. You're still just making whatever you want that makes you feel good. But there are a lot of moments where Matty just won't sit still in a chair and every morning you can hear [manager] Jamie on the other end of the phone trying to convince him that it is a good album and that it's not hopeless. It's the worst thing.

> MH: What did we call it - Friday feelings? Where I sit everyone down and I go, "Right, guys. We're not going to make this record. It's not going to happen. I just can't do it. I'm off." I have a full-on nervous breakdown for about six months.

> GD: To be honest, **after about four or five Fridays, you're just mindful of what happened last Friday.** I'm just like, "I'm not buying into this."

> MH: **At that point I just start going, "You know what? I think that I'm actually even catching myself in a cycle!** Let's just make it!"

**after about four or five Fridays, you're just mindful of what happened last Friday.**

Does this sentence mean that after four or five weeks passed, they’d start thinking carefully about what they thought about the album being not good enough last Friday might be a wrong idea?

**At that point I just start going, "You know what? I think that I'm actually even catching myself in a cycle!**

I don’t really get what **catching myself in a cycle** means. Does this mean that he doesn’t *really* think it’s a good album but he feels like he might be wrong about it?

Comment: This is two unrelated questions. If you really want the answers to both, please ask a separate question. Also, please make it clear that you've tried to answer the question yourself. Do you already know what "mindful" means, for instance?

Comment: Ah sorry, I understand the basic meaning of mindful but don’t  really get how to interpret it here. I’ll make a post per one question and try to make it clearer about what I don’t get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after about four or five Fridays, you're just mindful of what happened last Friday.

- You are only really thinking about (or remembering, or focusing on) the events of the previous Friday.

"You know what? I think that I'm actually even catching myself in a cycle!

- caught in a repeating loop of events.  Might also be caught in a rut which means that you are not really progressing.